# AngularJS Validation - ng-messages-multiple not displaying multiple errors

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

All,

I am working on an AngularJS form and am trying to see how the ng-messages directive works with ng-messages-multiple. I can't seem to get it to pick up multiple errors. I expect to see both the required and minimum errors at the same time but for some reason I only see required, then minimum. I posted the HTML below. I have the ng-messages included using bower, the script call in my index.html page, and I am injecting into my app.js module as required.

I am using AngularJS v1.3.2 in this project.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Validation Test Form</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="submit(form)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          ng-model="formModel.name"
          minlength="5"
          required/>
          <div ng-messages="form.name.$error" ng-messages-multiple class="has-error">
            <div ng-message="required">Required!</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">Minimum length is 5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    {{formError}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ng-minlength` instead `minlength`

```
<input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          ng-model="formModel.name"
          ng-minlength="5"
          required/>
```

instead

```
<input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          ng-model="formModel.name"
          minlength="5"
          required/>
```

**EDIT**

It is normal behaviour for ng-minlength directive, this directive validate only when we have not 0 size of input, entered a value it must be at least 5 characters long, but it's ok to leave the field empty, and, unfortunately, in anyway you don't achieve, that you want. I offer you to create your custom directive or see in direction ng-pattern directive with need behaviour, if you very want that showing two message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the change but the error does not display at all now.